# Gsview 6.0 options to create SCCM package

Tags: sccm

What switches or options can be used to uncheck JPG and PNG files from the default app association during the install process? Building an SCCM deployment and need those options unchecked as part of the install.

Comment: On which os do you want to deploy this? In Windows 10 this method of a program automatically setting associations is impossible anyway so you would not have to worry

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows 10, need to be able to deploy this without it changing the default app assoc. for JPG and PNG files. Or would I need to just deploy with defaults and config in registry. If so what could I change there?

Comment: What I meant is in Windows 10 assoc, the registry method or any way for a program to automate the associations is not allowed anymore. Microsoft allows only 2 methods gpo and manual user selction via ui so you don't have to worry there imo. Win 7 is different though. I could sadly find no method indicating that there is a switch for this the old gsview 5.0 docu however suggests that the files can just be copied (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsviewen.htm#Manual_Installation) maybe this is true for 6.0 as well. You could open the exe in 7zip and try